# Dividing each row of data frames within a list by a corresponding matrix value

Tags: r, loops, matrix, indexing, bioinformatics

I have a list of 3 data frames, each with 3 rows (`op2`) and a matrix (`rep_totals`). Each row of each data frame relates to a value in my matrix, with the trend: `op2[[i]][j,]` corresponding to `rep_totals[i,j]`

I would like to divide each row of each data frame in `op2` by its corresponding value in `rep_total`s to yield a list of 3 new data frames (`gt_freqs`) with their adjusted values.

Here is what I have tried:

```
x = matrix(5,3,5) # creating example
x = as.data.frame(x)
op2 = list(x,x,x)
rep_totals = matrix(5,3,3)

gt_freqs <- replicate(length(op2), matrix(0, 3, 5), simplify = FALSE)
for(i in seq_along(op2)) for(j in seq_along(op2[[1]][1:3,])) gt_freqs[[i]] <- op2[[i]][j,]/rep_totals[i,j]
```

So in this example the intended output would be 3 data frames of the same size as `op2`, except the values would all be adjusted to 1

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map`

```
Map(`/`,op2, asplit(rep_totals, 1))
```

---

With a `for` loop, it would be

```
for(i in seq_along(op2)) get_freqs[[i]] <- op2[[i]]/rep_totals[i,]
```

Comment: Thanks! I must have flipped around the matrix in my head because it worked like a charm when I changed the margin of `asplit` to 2

Comment: @eabrown2378 With `MARGIN = 2`, it is splitting by column, I assume that you want to split by row, so used `MARGIN = 1`